# Why is my Authorization Header giving me a 401 in Guzzle?

Tags: php, guzzle

I am getting a 401 on Guzzle 4.2 and the same setup works on Postman. Code below.

```
// Create a client with a base URL
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_url' => 'cloud.feedly.com/v3/streams/contents?streamId=user/user-id/category/global.all&count=1']);

    // Send a request to https://github.com/notifications
    $response = $client->get();

    //Auth
   $response->addHeader('Authorization', "auth-code");


    //send
    $r = $response->send();

   dd($r->json());
```

The error is:

```
GuzzleHttp \ Exception \ ClientException (401) 
Client error response [url] cloud.feedly.com/v3/streams/contents?streamId=user/user-id/global.all&count=1 [status code] 401 [reason phrase] Unauthorized
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation page](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/clients.html#creating-a-client) as per this line:

```
$response = $client->get();
```

It will send a get request, with no authorisation, hence the 401 response.

Try the following instead

```
// Create a client with a base URL.
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$request = $client-> createRequest('GET', 'cloud.feedly.com/v3/streams/contents?streamId=user/user-id/category/global.all&count=1');

$request->setHeader('Authorization', "auth-code");

// Send.
$response = $client->send($request);

dd($response->json());
```

The above creates a request, set the authorisation header on it. Then once prepared it actually sends it.

I think it worked in Postman because your headers are set, if you remove the authorization header it will likely fail there too.

I have not tested this but think it will work.

Comment: example using `->get`: `$requestOptions = ['allow_redirects' => true]; if($testServerReqHttpAuth) { $requestOptions['auth'] = ['usrnm','pwd'];} $response = $client->get($url, $requestOptions);`

Answer (score 1):

```
$response = $client->get('GET', 'cloud.feedly.com/v3/streams/contents?streamId=user/user-id/category/global.all&count=1', ['auth' =>  ['YOUR_USERNAME', 'YOUR_PASSWORD']]);
```

The 401 error means you should authenticate yourself with a valid username and password

Regards