# PHP cURL conversion to Guzzle

Tags: php, symfony, curl, guzzle

I'm working on integration with sentione api.
I have problem with guzzle, guzzle throws me 401 Unauthorized exception.
I think it can be problem with post data, I tried to set it in another way, but I'm getting always the same result.

That's my code:

```
        $arr = array(
            'topicId' => id, 
            'from' => '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000 CET'
        );
        $params = json_encode($arr);

        $client = new Client('http://sentione.com/api', array(
            'request.options' => array(
                'headers' => array(
                        "Accept: application/json",        
                        "X-API-KEY: key",
                        "Content-type: application/json",
                    )
                )
        ));

        $request = $client->post('statements/search', array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'), $params);
        $response = $request->send();
```

And that's my cURL definition:

```
$arr = array(
    "topicId" => id, 
    "from" => "2014-01-01 00:00:00.000 CET"
);

$json = json_encode($arr);

$headers = array(
        "Accept: application/json",        
        "X-API-KEY: key",
        "Content-type: application/json",
);
$url = "http://sentione.com/api/statements/search";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

Of course it's working great.
Anybody can help me? Maybe I forgot sth?

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in this construction:

```
    $client = new Client('http://sentione.com/api', array(
        'request.options' => array(
            'headers' => array(
                    "Accept: application/json",        
                    "X-API-KEY: key",
                    "Content-type: application/json",
                )
            )
    ));
```

There is information about difference between versions of Guzzle client in part of creating requests.
Check here:

### https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/777

[Why is my Authorization Header giving me a 401 in Guzzle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396047/why-is-my-authorization-header-giving-me-a-401-in-guzzle)