# Laravel send mail with MailGun

Tags: php, email, laravel

i install guzzle for sending mail with mailgun, i create mailgun account

this is my mail.php

```
'driver' => 'mailgun',
'host' => 'smtp.mailgun.org',
'port' => 587,
'from' => array('address' =>'my@gmail.com','name'=>'My Name'),
'encryption' => 'tls',
'username' => null,
'password' => null,
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => false,
```

and my services.php

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => 'sandboxexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mailgun.org',
    'secret' => 'key-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
],
```

but i get error, i have setting it right, but what is the problem?

`ClientException` in `Middleware.php` line 69:

`Client error: 401`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396047/why-is-my-authorization-header-giving-me-a-401-in-guzzle this is helpful

Comment: what error are you getting

Comment: the error is ClientException in Middleware.php line 69:

Client error: 401

Comment: i read the link you give, but it's different from my error.. my program error when sending email.. i'm using Sentinel and when i reset password and enter email. the error was the same like i send email like above

Comment: in Middleware.php line 69
at Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(object(Response)) in Promise.php line 199
at Promise::callHandler('1', object(Response), array(object(Promise), object(Closure), null)) in Promise.php line 152
at Promise::GuzzleHttp\Promise\{closure}() in TaskQueue.php line 60
at TaskQueue->run() in CurlMultiHandler.php line 96
at CurlMultiHandler->tick() in CurlMultiHandler.php line 123
at CurlMultiHandler->execute(true) in Promise.php line 240
at Promise->invokeWaitFn() in Promise.php line 217
at Promise->waitIfPending() in Promise.php line 261